# Linq to entity: How to groupby date part of datetime

Tags: c#-4.0, linq-to-entities

I would like to simply query table *Flights*, contains datetime field *Arrival*, and group results by date, then add paging using linq to entity.

How can we group flights by arrival dates?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're looking for something simple, try this out.

```
int recordsPerPage = 10, currentIndex = 0;
var groupQuery =
    myDC.Flights.
    GroupBy(f => EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(f.Arrival)).
    Skip(recordsPerPage * currentIndex).
    Take(recordsPerPage);
```

This will give you back groups of Flight objects which you can use however you plan.

Comment: Entity framework doesn't support your simple solution to fetch data from entities! `.Date` in `f.Arrival.Date` is not supported in linq to entity.

Comment: @Reza You're totally right, I answered LinqToSql when you wanted Entities.  Answer updated.

Comment: I have been looking for this for a very long time!

Comment: Note: EntityFunctions is replaced by System.Data.Entity.DbFunctions in EF6.